# Compilation script

Tags: c, linux, compilation, automation

I want to know a good way to compile a program that uses many files and I want to avoid to recompile unmodified files.

It is for Linux, and I am looking for something that is different from Makefile.

Makefile has some problems:
It is long to write, and it is verbose to change as long I create new files; C/C++ use header files.
Makefile does not recompile a .c file if it includes a .h file that includes another .h file that was modified. It needs complex syntax.
Makefile uses the  tabulation character, it is not good, because I use the tab key to indentation (it inserts 4 space chars instead).

As an example, my original compilation script is:

```
gcc file1.c -c -flags1
gcc file2.c -c -flags2
gcc file3.c file4.c -c -flags3
gcc file1.o file2.o file3.o file4.o -o a.out
```

And I want to avoid to recompile what is not needed with easy ways.

Comment: One has to wonder what's the deal with the different flags for each .c file.

Comment: Note that your four-spaces problem is a deficiency in your editor (or editor setup), not with `make` itself. Any editor that can't allow you to insert arbitrary characters is brain-dead.

Comment: Concerning the tabs in the makefiles, there's `.RECIPEPREFIX` if you want something else.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't like the idea of using a building software (like `make` or something else). And you can always put your compilation command inside a shell script (but I recommend using `omake` or `make`). See my reply http://stackoverflow.com/a/8692140/841108

Comment: I configure the editors to use spaces instead of tabulation. It is helpful for indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some projects (Doom3, MongoDB and others) use [SCons](http://www.scons.org/).

It's written in Python and has many features (like parallel compilation).

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**: The Make Tutorial mentioned in this post no longer exists which is a terrible shame as it was a really good introduction.

Makefiles can be seamless, you can have it automatically compile your project based purely on the files in the project directories. See this [Make Tutorial](http://www.eng.hawaii.edu/Tutor/Make/). After that tutorial you will have learned to create dynamic Makefile scripts that compile only what has been modified, and follows the dependency tree.

But if you want to see some further wizardry, have a look at the [DevKitPro](http://devkitpro.org/) makefiles, they go as far as figuring out **header dependencies** too using what I can only presume to be the use of **grep**. Feel free to modify it for your own projects.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use some other builder, like e.g. the [omake build system](http://omake.metaprl.org/) or [P.Millier's cook system](http://miller.emu.id.au/pmiller/software/cook/) etc. I think `omake` is very powerful. The disadvantage of using other builders is that `make` is usually available on every Linux system, but it is not the case of `omake` (or `cmake` or `cook`).

Don't forget that `make` dependencies can be generated by `gcc` with several [preprocessor options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) like `-M` etc. In practice, you can use GNU make tricks to avoid writing complex `Makefile`-s.

Good editors like e.g. [emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) provide you specific modes to help editing (& highlighting) `Makefile`-s.

You could use (even inside `Makefile`-s or with `omake` or other builder) the [ccache](http://ccache.samba.org/) compiler cache (and it can be used "transparently" by symlinking it as `gcc`).

You could distribute your compilation to other machines on the local network with e.g. [distcc](http://code.google.com/p/distcc/) or [icecream](http://en.opensuse.org/Icecream). Of course, many builders allow parallel compilations (e.g. `make -j`).

There exists several `Makefile` generators, notably the GNU [autotools](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/automake/manual/html_node/Autotools-Introduction.html) suite and [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/)

Don't forget to use a version control system (like GIT) for your source codes.

Comment: +1: I've used OMake and it is really simple to use and equally expressive.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a easier way to use makefile and it works. There is no tabulation. With `touch`, I can force header dependent compilation.

```
myexe.out: file1.o file2.o;\
g++ file1.o file2.o -o myexe.out

file1.o: file1.cpp;\
g++ -c file1.cpp -flags1

file2.o: file2.cpp header1.hpp;\
g++ -c file2.cpp -flags2

header1.hpp: header2.hpp;\
touch header1.hpp
```

I will try SCons.
Thanks to everyone.

Comment: You should also look into `omake` !